# Converting json data to html with div loop

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I have the following result and wanted to display a loop of html divs from the result. But all attempts have failed.

```
<?php   
$location = $_GET['location'];
$checkin = $_GET['check_in'];
$checkout= $_GET['check_out'];
$adult= $_GET['adult'];
$child= $_GET['child'];
$handle = curl_init();
$url = "https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/hotels/search-airport?apikey=Gaois6WPa9VQ7WhxqqfV2XsD7J5gMMHX&location=$location&check_in=$checkin&check_out=$checkout&amenity=RESTAURANT&amenity=RESTAURANT&number_of_results=2";


curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec($handle); 
curl_close($handle);       
echo $output;
?>

<script>
var data = $output;
for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < length; i++) {
var temp = '<tr><td>' + data[i].id + '</td>';
temp+= '<td>' + data[i].property_code+ '</td>';
temp+= '<td>' + data[i].property_name+ '</td>';
temp+= '<td>' + data[i].location+ '</td></tr>';
$('table tbody').append(temp));
}
</script>
```

It does provide the the array but failed to produce the html-table with the according data

Comment: Why you mixed javascript and php?

Comment: Sorry, i made mistake in putting the lines of code, have placed the right markup

Comment: `var data = $output;` you forgot to echo it, plus the tags of course

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that your are, as you stated in the question, actually returning valid json data from the amadeus api then perhaps the following might be of interest. Rather than using string concatenation the following uses conventional DOM manipulation methods which, imo, is a better approach.

As was pointed out in the first comment - why mix PHP and javascript like this? If the requests are being made by the client in response to the user selecting options in a form ( for instance ) and the request is fired by javascript/ajax then I can understand the need to use javascript to process the response but for a static page or a conventional form submission there really is no need to use javascript.

I fetch the code using a PHP function called `curl` which is not shown here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>AMADEUS - JSON TO HTML</title>
        <style>
            table{width:100%;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;display:table; border:1px solid black;background:whitesmoke;}
            th{background:gray;color:white;}
            tr{display:table-row;background:white;}
            tr:nth-of-type(odd){background:whitesmoke;}
            td{padding:0.5rem;margin:0.1rem;display:table-cell;border:1px dotted gray;}
        </style>
        <?php
            /* assign javascript variable with json data */
            echo "
        <script>
            let json=$output;
        </script>";
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table id='amadeus'>
            <!-- an empty table.. -->
        </table>


        <script>
            /* simple function to add a new table cell */
            const addcell=function(data,parent){
                let td=document.createElement('td');
                    td.innerText=data;
                parent.appendChild( td );
            };

            let tbl=document.getElementById( 'amadeus' );
            let results=json.results;
            let properties=['property_code','property_name','location'];
            console.info( results )

            let tr=document.createElement('tr');
                tbl.appendChild( tr );

            properties.forEach( function( prop ){
                let th=document.createElement('th');
                    th.setAttribute('scope','col');
                    th.innerText=prop;

                tr.appendChild( th );
            });


            results.forEach( function(obj){
                tr=document.createElement('tr');
                tbl.appendChild( tr );

                /* Alternative method to get data into cells */
                addcell( obj.property_code, tr );
                addcell( obj.property_name, tr );
                addcell( [obj.location.latitude, obj.location.longitude ].join(','), tr );


            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

modified code above now generates similar to the following:
[image: example output]

Comment: Cool, it works like magic, i really need to polish my fundamental understanding about this. much appreciated for your kind effort and guidance. God bless you

Comment: https://halaltrekker.com/staging2/hotel-search2.php?apikey=Gaois6WPa9VQ7WhxqqfV2XsD7J5gMMHX&location=BKK&check_in=2018-10-29&check_out=2018-10-31&radius=50&lang=EN&CY=USD&number_of_results=20

By the way, what makes the address column shown as [object Object]?
How do i access that array?

Comment: var properties=['property_code','property_name','location[]->latitude'];
How do i access latitude / longitude?
I tried the above syntax but made no success

Comment: Instead of processing the array (`properties`) again for adding the actual data you could manually add a table cell for each item - and that way you could access `location.latitude` and `location.longitude` etc.... I simply used the array for convenience in the example.

Comment: Does it means like this ? 

    let properties=['property_code','property_name','location.latitude'];

Comment: I just tried the recent changes you recommended on combining 2 objects. it works charmly, and now trying to combine amount and currency symbol by following the same method :)

How do I make some contribution to you personally, you saved a lot of my time

Comment: if I helped just accept the answer and perhaps upvote too - other than that nothing else required

Comment: That's very kind of you RamRaider, I wish the best in your future undertaking and endeavor. Still, Looking forward to get as much knowledge and guidance from you in near future :)

Comment: How do i create a link to the content?
And also how to make <img src>

I tried the following code but not successful

    addcell('<a href="'+obj._links.more_rooms_at_this_hotel.href+'">View</a>',tr);

it ads " in the front of the value and " at the end